# Avoid error <yourObject> is not defined in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, stream, rrule

Every time that I install a bower module for my Ember.js application, when I added them inside my `ember-cli-build.js`I can use it inside components, controllers, services, etc. But JSHint give me an error like following:

```
'RRule' is not defined.
```

or

```
'Stream' is not defined.
```

How can I void them?

This is my imports in `ember-cli-build.js`:

```
  app.import('bower_components/rrule/lib/rrule.js');
  app.import('bower_components/rrule/lib/nlp.js');
  app.import('bower_components/streamjs/stream.js');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In file `.jshintrc`, add `"RRule"` and `"Stream"` to `predef` section

Comment: You can also use magic comments, and at the top of the file that uses the global put `/* global RRule */`.